# Vector autoregression with multiple trials?

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

I have a dataset consisting of multiple time series, recorded from an experiment. Since I have multiple trials (repetitions) of the same experiment, I would like to take advantage of these trials and allow a vector autoregression (VAR) model to be built using for e.g. 70% of these trials and then test the forecasting ability on the remaining 30% of these trials, as is typically done in model evaluation. However I can't seem to find a VAR model package/software that accepts multiple trials - they all seem to work with single trials of multivariate time series (i.e. only one observation of each variable is expected at each time point). I've gone ahead and added a "time elapsed" column to the dataset and then concatenated all my trials together, but I'm at a loss on how to proceed without having to come up with some custom optimization procedure.

I would like to learn about any package or method that is relevant to multivariate time series analysis with multiple trials.